# Función con bucle for y array deja de funcionar en la segunda vuelta del bucle

Tags: array, c, funciones, bucle-for

Tengo la siguiente función en lenguaje c, la cual al llegar al elemento: `array[i][1][1]` y solicitar al usuario que introduzca el dato el programa deja de funcionar.

```
int introducir_resultados(int array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3], int num_municipios, int num_partidos)

int n, i, num_votos, num_candidatos, num_candidatos_no;

for (i=0;i<num_municipios;i++)
{
    printf("****Municipio %d****\n\n", i);
    for(n=0;n<num_partidos;n++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca numero de votos para el partido %d\n", n);
        scanf("%d", &num_votos);
        array[i][n][0] = num_votos;
        printf("Introduzca numero de candidatos elegidos del partido %d\n", n);
        scanf("%d", &num_candidatos);
        array[i][n][1] = num_candidatos;
        printf("Introduzca numero de candidatos no elegidos para el partido %d\n", n);
        scanf("%d", &num_candidatos_no);
        array[i][n][2] = num_candidatos_no;
    }
}
return array[num_municipios][num_partidos][3];
```

¿Alguien sabe que puede causar el error? Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Adjunto el método main() y la declaración de las funciones por si resulta de ayuda para solucionar mi pregunta, gracias.

```
#define NUMMUNICIPIOS 10
#define NUMPARTIDOS 10

int menu();
int introducir_resultados(int array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3], int num_municipios, int num_partidos);
void visualizar_municipio(int array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3], int num_municipios, int num_partidos);

int main()
{
    int num_municipios, num_partidos, opcion, array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3];
    opcion = menu();
    if (opcion == 1)
    {
        printf("Introduzca numero de municipios (max = 10)\n");
        scanf("%d", &num_municipios);
        while (num_municipios > NUMMUNICIPIOS)
        {
            printf("Introduzca un numero valido\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_municipios);
        }
        printf("Introduzca numero de partidos (max = 10)\n");
        scanf("%d", &num_partidos);
        while (num_partidos > NUMPARTIDOS)
        {
            printf("Introduzca un numero valido\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_partidos);
        }
        array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3] = introducir_resultados(array[NUMMUNICIPIOS][NUMPARTIDOS][3], num_municipios, num_partidos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que la función devuelve una posición no válida:

```
return array[num_municipios][num_partidos][3];
//                                         ^ valores validos: 0, 1, 2
```

Por otro lado, no hace falta que uses una variable temporal para leer de la entrada estándar, puedes almacenar el dato directamente en el array:

```
// Cambia esto
scanf("%d", &num_votos);
array[i][n][0] = num_votos;

// Por esto
scanf("%d", &array[i][n][0]);
```

Por lo demás no veo otros errores. Si lo del `return` no soluciona tu problema deberás proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que nos permita reproducir el error

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me ha propuesto pero sigue dándome error el programa, adjunto el main() por si resulta de ayuda. Por otro lado, si cambio el indice [ 3 ] por [ 2 ] siempre que aparece el array, el error me lo da en array[1][1][1] en lugar de en array[1][1][2]

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo, el problema estaba en declarar el array en el argumento de la función en lugar de declararla dentro de esta y utilizar como argumentos solo las dos variables que indican el tamaño del array.